# WPF Custom Component Datagrid binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

So, I am trying to perform some databinding to a custom component that I have, but I can't seem to find any good information on how to do so. What I would like to do is just have the custom component in the main window to have a Bindning property...

```
<local:MultiColumnComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" x:Name="NewCombo"></local:MultiColumnComboBox>
```

And then in custom component...

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" Name="dataGrid"></DataGrid>
```

If anyone knows how to do this, some guidance would be appreciated :)

**Edit**

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IList<Customer>), typeof(MultiColumnComboBox));
public MultiColumnComboBox()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
//Items Source Binding
public IList<Customer> ItemsSource
{
    get 
    { 
        return (IList<Customer>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); 
    }
    set 
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Binding");
        System.Console.WriteLine(value);
        SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using DependencyProperty. This is the most complete and easy to understand link I've ever found. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224230/Exploring-the-use-of-Dependency-Properties-in-User

Comment: Thanks, I've actually seen this, but in that project **public IEnumerable ItemsSource** (the part that I need) gives an error and requests that you add 1 type argument.

Comment: Also, if I use the recommended **System.Collections.IEnumerable** It gives the error **A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'ItemsSource' property of type 'MultiColumnComboBox'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out!

All you have to do is use the DataContext property from the control so in your main page..

```
<local:custom control DataContext="{Binding Something}" />
```

And in your custom control, I bound...

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=UOMControl}"
```

and that was it.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten the Binding error you are seeing when I pass the wrong ownerType to DependencyProperty.Register method... please check to make sure you're using typeof(MultiColumnComboBox) as shown below.

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MultiColumnComboBox.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MultiColumnComboBox : UserControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This creates the dependency property for the collection to display.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IList<Customer>), typeof(MultiColumnComboBox));

    /// <summary>
    /// This property gets you to the collection that's being displayed.
    /// </summary>
    public IList<Customer> ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IList<Customer>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public MultiColumnComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you set the Binding ElementName in your UserControl so that it has the right DataContext.

```
<UserControl x:Class="DependencyPropertyExample.MultiColumnComboBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Name="userControl1">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsSource, ElementName=userControl1}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: A couple of things (sorry it's been so long, I've been away from a computer for a while), so far I'm not able to get this to work. It doesn't recognize the binding. I know the sample database is set up correctly because I have a datagrid that I can bind it to that works fine. Also, the IList declarations in the code above include the type as Customer, however this control won't always have Customer as the items source, so yeah. I've got the code that I have so far. I didn't include the non-essentials...